# Why am I getting FeatureNotSupported exception in PhoneDialer.Open in iOS but working fine in Android in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I am using Xamarin Essentials
PhoneDialer.Open(string number)

Working fine in Android emulator but not working in iOS. Throwing error FeatureNotSupported while trying in simulator.

The number is in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Throwing error FeatureNotSupported while trying in simulator.

You need to test this feature in **a physical iOS device**, then it will work.

Comment: Thank you. I too noticed that there is no dialer implemented in the simulator by Apple. Hence the FeatureNotSupported Exception.

Comment: try
            {
                PhoneDialer.Open(phoneNum);
            }catch (ArgumentNullException anEx)
            {
              
                // Number was null or white space
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
            {
               
                // Phone Dialer is not supported on this device.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                // Other error has occurred.
            }.

Comment: But the debugger does not enter the FeatureNoTSupportedException block, but throws the error in Application class for iOS project and crashes.

Comment: @shilpajomon It's strange. But it seems no meaning to test it in simulator.